Trusted code to test that a Bitcoin address corresponds to a certain private key
I apologise for asking a possibly trivial question. I am not much of a programmer and that's my problem.
In an answer to another question about obtaining the Bitcoin address from a private key the following is stated:
A Bitcoin address is computed as follows:

A private key is a 256-bit integer $k$ below 0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141, the order of the group $E(\mathbb F_p)$ of $\mathbb F_p$-rational points on the curve [secp256k1], $E/\mathbb F_p: y^2 = x^3 + 7$ where $p$ is the prime $2^{256} - 2^{32} - 2^9 - 2^8 - 2^7 - 2^6 - 2^4 - 1$.

A public key is the standard encoding $\underline P$ of a point $P = [k]B$ on secp256k1, the scalar multiplication by $k$ of the standard base point $B \in E(\mathbb F_p)$.

An address is the ‘base58’ encoding of the string $\text{‘1’} \mathbin\Vert h \mathbin\Vert c$, where $h = \operatorname{RIPEMD160}(\operatorname{SHA256}(\underline P))$ and $c$ is the first four bytes of $\operatorname{SHA256}(\operatorname{SHA256}(\text{‘1’} \mathbin\Vert h))$.


My question is is there trusted/audited code (preferably in a high level language such as pari/gp, magma, sage, but not necessarily) that can be run on a local computer (not online) for testing that a bitcoin address corresponds to a certain private key.
Any pointers appreciated. I suppose there are github pages containing such code, but again, I am unable to judge such code as being correct. For example the code would need to do the standard encodings in the relevant algebraic structures.
Another relevant question, which was pointed out in the comments under this question is this one.

So this is a software recommendation question?

@DannyNiu, I guess.

I see, you want to be safe from scammers like BrainWallet—Bitcoin has tons of questions about wallets. Could you tell us what does mean do the standard encodings in the relevant algebraic structures. in more explicitly?

@kelalaka, that language may be overkill. I am referring to the "standard encoding" in item 2, and "base58" in item 3, but I guess what I want is that the address is eventually displayed correctly, in whatever standard encoding it needs to be in. Of course it is no problem to convert to base 58 but there would be big-endian, little-endian issues possibly.

For example, see row 47 (nothing special about it except the key is not tiny) of the list of private keys and addresses in this page: https://privatekeys.pw/puzzles/bitcoin-puzzle-tx. Assuming this data is genuine, I'd want to verify that the listed address corresponds to the listed private key.

This might be enough https://pypi.org/project/bitcoinaddress/

Is this to prevent against kleptography, i.e. a backdoored key generation algorithm?

@lamontap, yes that would be an outcome of such trusted software

Strictly speaking, the address is ripemd160(sha256(pubkey)) (and is relative to a network). The base58check encoding was standard, or at least uniquitous, for years, but since 2017 it has largely been replaced by bech32; see my comment on the previous answer you link. [moderator note: added links, including to the re-posted comment].
